# How do I connect mysql to phpmyadmin via devlibox?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I don't know if the term "connect" will be the right term, but I cannot figure out anything else.

So I started using devilbox in Ubuntu 22.04 and when I tried running this code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = ""; $database = "college";
// Create connection $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username,$password, $database);
// Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } // echo "Connected successfully"; ?>
```

and I faced this issue:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No such file or 
directory in /shared/httpd/my_project/Library-Book-Management-System/dbconfig/connect.php:8
 Stack trace: #0 /shared/httpd/my_project/Library-Book-
Management-System/dbconfig/connect.php(8): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', '', 'college') #1 {main} thrown in /shared/httpd/my_project/Library-Book-Management-System/dbconfig/connect.php on line 8
```

I have the database in my mysql server and I made another in phpmyadmin, also i unhashed my msql version from env file yet I am seeing this over and over again